# How to log into stackoverflow.com through python?

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

I was thinking is there any way I can log into my stackoverflow.com account through my `python code`.

Is there any `stackoverflow-pythonAPI` through which I can achieve the above task.

I googled before asking here but was not able to find any API nor any `Hello World` example of using it with python.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "logging in"?  Does this mean you want to tell your browser to log in?  Or do you want to access non-public profile information prgramatically?

Comment: I want to access `non-public profile information`.

Comment: @Wooble: Really?  I did not find any solution yet.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck: there is both an [API](https://stackapps.com/about) and there is are at least two python libraries ([Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python) and [Stack.PY](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api)) to use that API.

One caveat: Personal information requires that you use the v2.0 API, but the currently released version of Py-StackExchange only supports up to version 1.1. The [GitHub repository for the library](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange) has a [updating-2.0 branch](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tree/updating-2.0) that may or may not work for you. Stack.PY *does* support version 2.0 (and 2.1 too!).

The API itself is based on HTTP requests with JSON responses, so you could just call the API directly as well.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to authenticate using this library, or if this is even possible?

Comment: I vaguely remember that access to the private information is only possible with version 2.0 of the API, and this library only support version 1.1, so I have some doubts this answers the question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah, you are correct: [Announcing API version 1.1](http://stackapps.com/q/1999)

Comment: The github repo for this library has an "updating-2.0" branch for v.2 of the API, although I haven't confirmed that it actually works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But I cannot access the non-public profile information becuase it seems I cannot authenticate myself.

Comment: @Noob: Updated the answer a little.